# How do I print out the text of a specific xml element in python?

Tags: python-3.x, xml

My xml file is in this format:

```
<data>
    <dict>
        <key>Major Version</key><integer>1</integer>
        <key>Minor Version</key><integer>3</integer>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>Major Version</key><integer>5</integer>
        <key>Minor Version</key><integer>6</integer>
    </dict>
</data>
```

I'm trying to print out the text of a specific xml element...for example, i want to only print out the value 1 or 5 for the key element "Major Version".  How do I do that?

My Python code (Python3) currently looks like this:

```
fname = input('Enter filename: ')
if len(fname) < 1:
    fname = 'librarytest.xml'

doc = ET.parse(fname)
doc_content = doc.getroot()

chk_tag = False

for dict in doc_content:
    chk_tag = False
    for ele in dict:
        if ele.tag == 'key' and ele.text == 'Major Version':
            chk_tag = True
        if chk_tag and ele.tag == 'integer':
            print(ele.text)
```

It returns all the values of Integer tag

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you are probably looking for something like this:

```
vers =  doc_content.findall('.//key')
ints =  doc_content.findall('.//integer')
for v, i in zip(vers,ints):
    if v.text == "Major Version":
        print(i.text)
```

Output:

```
1
5
```

Comment: Thanks Jack for your response, figured it out doing it another way... def lookup(key_text):
    chk_tag = False

    for ele in dict:
        if chk_tag:
            return ele.text

        if ele.tag == 'key' and ele.text == key_text:
            chk_tag = True
    return None

........
for dict in doc_content:
    if (lookup('Track ID')) is None:
        continue

    name = lookup('Name')

Comment: @tulipz123 If that's your solution, you should post it as an answer, not a comment.